# How to Access JSON Object contains json in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I want to show the data name, age, address in Angular2 DataTable or any other grid view controls in Angular2

```
[{
        "status": 1,
        "message": "Records Found",
        "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "data": {
                "name": "Joseph",
                "age": "25",
                "Address": "Trichy",

            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "data": {
                "name": "John",
                "age": "35",
                "Address": "Chennai",
            }
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "data": {
                "name": "martin",
                "age": "25",
                "Address": "Chennai",
            }
        }]
}];
```

Comment: what ? explain your question

Comment: i want show the data name,age,address in Angular2 DataTable  or any other grid view controls in angular2

Comment: Add these lines to your question

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question json as `response`

```
this.data = response[0].data;

<li *ngFor="let d of data">
  {{d?.name}}
  {{d?.age}}
  {{d?.Address}}
</li>
```

In case your first array (json ) has multiple objects and then use nested ngFor

Answer (score 0):

**Pojo Classes**

```
  export class Data {
      name: string;
      age: string;
      Address: string;
  }

  export class Datum {
      id: string;
      data: Data;
  }

  export class RootObject {
      status: number;
      message: string;
      data: Datum[];
  }
```

In Component.ts

```
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {

    a: any;
    rootObj: RootObject = new RootObject();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.a = [{
            "status": 1,
                    "message": "Records Found",
                    "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                        "data": {
                    "name": "Joseph",
                            "age": "25",
                            "Address": "Trichy",

                }
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                        "data": {
                    "name": "John",
                            "age": "35",
                            "Address": "Chennai",
                }
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                        "data": {
                    "name": "martin",
                            "age": "25",
                            "Address": "Chennai",
                }
            }]
        }]

        this.rootObj = this.a;

        console.log(this.rootObj.data[0].data.age)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In html :- 
     `<table [mfData]="data[0].data" #mf="mfDataTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
                    <td>{{item.data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.data.Address}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.data.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>`

In Component.ts :-

```
 `data = [{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Records Found",
  "data": [{
  "id": "1",
  "data": {
    "name": "Joseph",
    "age": "25",
    "Address": "Trichy"
  }
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "data": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "35",
    "Address": "Chennai"
  }
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "data": {
    "name": "martin",
    "age": "25",
    "Address": "Chennai"
  }
}]`
```

Comment: its worked fine for the <li>. i want to show data in angular2 Datatable. here only i have issue.

Comment: For angular2 Datatable this work for me.  
        <table [mfData]="data[0].data>
<tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
                    <td>{{item.data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.data.Address}}</td>
                    <td >{{item.data.age}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>